# Reverse proxy Ghost (Heroku app) from another app (expressjs)

Tags: heroku, express, http-proxy, ghost-blog, node-http-proxy

Simple case: I have app1 - which is an install of ghost (`site-blog.herokuapp.com`). I have app2, which is a custom express.js app (`site.herokuapp.com`).

I want to serve the blog from `site.herokuapp.com/blog`.

For Ghost, here's part of my `config.js`

```
  production: {
    url: process.env.BLOG_IDENTIFIER_URL,
    fileStorage: false,
    database: {
      client: 'postgres',
      connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      debug: false
    },
    server: {
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: process.env.PORT
    }
  },
```

`BLOG_IDENTIFIER_URL` is set to `site.herokuapp.com/blog`.

For the express.js app, I have the following routing (for `/blog`):

```
router.all('*', function(req, res) {
  //  blog page is actually a ghost!
  var blog_url = 'http://localhost:2368';
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    blog_url = 'http://site-blog.herokuapp.com';
  }
  req.headers.host = blog_url;
  require('http-proxy').createProxyServer().web(req, res, { target: blog_url });
});
```

This works absolutely fine locally, but when I push both the repos to heroku, and try to visit `site.herokuapp.com/blog`, I get just a blank page and nothing in the logs. The request fails though:

[image: Imgur]

I have tried a lot of stuff, both from SO and from the rest of the visible internet. Nothing seems to work. I'm stuck here for the last 4 hours. If you have anything that might help, please please leave a comment or an answer.

Comment: It's several months after... Did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: I did not. I opted to just use a separate app without proxying anything.